# Multiple excel tables in Outlook with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to send Outlook email with 3 excel tables.

- I have one excel file - master_file.csv (this file is filled with automated data from pandas data frame)
- In this file I have one sheet (Sheet1) with 3 tables
- These tables have always the same number of columns:

  - table_1 from A to R
  - table_2 from S to AJ
  - table_3 from AK to BD
- Number of rows is changing every time so range for rows should be determined depending on filled cells (probably XlDirectionDown)
- These tables have their own formatting in Excel file - this formatting needs to be copied into the email

Email should look somethig like that:

'Text'

"Table 1'

'Text"

"Table 2"

"Text"

"Table 3"

"Text"

I already tried code below but can't figure it out all this together and I bumped into 100 of options which none of them works.

Can you help me out with problem of adding excel tables to outlook email when table needs to be determined based on filled cells in rows?

````
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client as win32
from PIL import ImageGrab

excel_path = str(Path.cwd() / 'master_file.xlsm')
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_path)
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

win32c = win32.constants
ws.Range("A1:R11").CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=win32c.xlBitmap)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
image_path = str(Path.cwd() / 'test.png')
img.save(image_path)

outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
new_mail.To = 'person@email.com'
new_mail.Attachments.Add(Source=image_path)
body = "<h1>Email text...</h1><br><br> <img src=test.png>"
new_mail.HTMLBody = (body)
new_mail.Display()
wb.Close()```
````

Comment: Have you considered converting the Excel file to HTML?

Comment: @Сергей Кох I edited question
@afarrag I converted to HTML and then did this:
`body = open(r'my_path\maste.htm').read()
new_mail.HTMLBody = (body)`
However now outlook shows 
"This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them."

Comment: I found a solution to frames and in general for a question. Will upload answer later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I found a solution and maybe it will be helpful for somebody.
There are actually 2 solutions but the second one is more suitable for nice email in my opinion.

First solution: We have one csv/excel file.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client as win32
from PIL import ImageGrab
import xlwings as xw

# open raw data file
filename_read = 'master_file.csv'
wb = xw.Book(filename_read)
sht = wb.sheets[0]

# find the numbers of columns and rows in the sheet
num_col = sht.range('A1').end('right').column
num_row = sht.range('A4').end('down').row

# collect data
content_list = sht.range((1,1),(num_row,num_col-1))


excel_path = str(Path.cwd() / 'master_file.xlsm')
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_path)
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

win32c = win32.constants
ws.Range(f'A1:R{num_row}').CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=win32c.xlBitmap)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
image_path1 = str(Path.cwd() / 'test.png')
img.save(image_path1)

win32c = win32.constants
ws.Range(f'S1:AJ{num_row}').CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=win32c.xlBitmap)
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
image_path2 = str(Path.cwd() / 'test2.png')
img.save(image_path2)

outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
new_mail.To = 'person@email.com'
new_mail.Attachments.Add(Source=image_path1)
new_mail.Attachments.Add(Source=image_path2)
body = "<h1>Hello team,</h1> <br><br> <h2> Here are data for yesterday.</h2> <br><br> <h2>Call Metrics:</h2> <br><br> <img src=test.png width=1700 height=600> <br><br> <h2>Back office metrics:</h2> <img src=test2.png width=1700 height=600> "

new_mail.HTMLBody = (body)
new_mail.Display()
wb.Close()
```

This code is searching for a table end and take a picture of it and put it to email. It is good solution when you have always sort of the same number of rows. But if that changes a lot (like one time 30 rows, and second time 100 rows) images will be too small or too big if you set up one fixed width and height like I did.

Second solution: Create one excel for one table (i.e. "table_1.xlsm", "table_2.xlsm"). Put there a simple VBA code

```
Sub auto_open()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    
    Range("A4:R200").Clear
    
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\master_source.csv"
    Windows("master_source.csv").Activate

    'This range below select data till rows are filled'
    Range("A2:R2", Range("B2:R2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select

    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("table_1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("A4").Select
    Sheet1.Paste
    Windows("master_source.csv").Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Windows("master_source.csv").Close
    
    Range("A2:R2", Range("B2:R2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
    Range("A2:R2", Range("B2:R2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A2:R2", Range("B2:R2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

  
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    Application.Quit
  
End Sub
```

Save this SHEET as Web Page - (!!) This is important - save JUST a sheet. If you save whole Workbook it will save with FRAMES, which Outlook doesn't support.
Save it and tick a square with AutoRepublish (after every save it will update our HTML file).
Then this Python code

```
import os, time, sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from pathlib import Path
import win32com.client as win32

#seting up yesterday date and date format
d = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
dt = d.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

#saving copy of the file for future usage
filepath = Path(f'C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/Agent report {d}.csv')
filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
master_df.to_csv(filepath)

#updating 3 tables - it opens every table file and then VBA doing it's job automatically as it is "auto_open"
for x in range(1, 4):
   os.system(f'start "excel" "C:\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\table_{x}.xlsm"')
   time.sleep(10)
            
    
outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application') 
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
               
mail.To = 'person@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = f'Agent report for {dt}'
    
table1 = open(r'C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\table_1.htm').read()
table2 = open(r'C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\table_2.htm').read()
table3 = open(r'C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\table_3.htm').read()

mail.HTMLBody = f"""\
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        
        Hello team,<br><br> 
        Below are metrics for your agents for previous day<br><br>
        
        <b>First Metrics:</b><br><br>
        
        {table1}<br><br>
            
        
        <b>Second metrics:</b><br><br>
        
        {table2}<br><br>
        
      
        <b>Third statistics:</b><br><br>
        
        {table3}<br>
        
        Reference:<br>

        
        Kind regards,<br>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
mail.Send()
```